# Change token expiry time on azure ad b2b directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

How to change Token expiry time in Azure Active Directory application without powershell? Token expire after 1hr, and refresh token is not working as I expected. We use adal.js for login and refresh token

Answer (score 3):

**You can't**. In Azure AD B2C you can configure the token lifetime within the Azure Portal but for the B2B Directory you have to do it with PowerShell.

See: [Configurable token lifetimes in Azure Active Directory (Public Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes)

Comment: I tried this, but it does not affect. How I can verify that my policy link to my B2B directory? I create policy using this command - New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @("{`"TokenLifetimePolicy`":{`"Version`":1, `"MaxAgeSingleFactor`"
:`"until-revoked`"}}") -DisplayName TenantDefaultPolicyScenario  -Type TokenLifetimePolicy  and link my application using Add-AzureADApplicationPolicy -Id:"Applicaiton object id" -RefObjectId:"policy id".

Comment: using Get-AzureAdPolicy and Get-AzureADPolicyAppliedObject

Comment: I tried Get-AzureADPolicyAppliedObject, get 'Get-AzureADPolicyAppliedObject : Error occurred while executing GetPolicyAppliedObject
Code: Directory_ObjectNotFound this error.

Comment: Then you did something wrong, the article explains what you have to do.